# Find a way to update the user passport with passport-local-mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack, passport-local

I'm creating an application with **nodejs** and **passport-local-mongoose**,
the problem is that i cannot find a way to update the user password since passport use Salt and Hash, there's some method or some way to update the password by a PUT method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've added the `passport-local-mongoose` plugin to your user schema, you should be able to call
`setPassword(password, cb)` on your user schema.

```
yourSchemaName.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
        if (err) //handle error
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) //handle error
            else //handle success
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the password you can use changePassword command.
here is an example

```
router.post('/changepassword', function(req, res) {
// Search for user in database
User.findOne({ _id: 'your id here' },(err, user) => {
  // Check if error connecting
  if (err) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: err }); // Return error
  } else {
    // Check if user was found in database
    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'User not found' }); // Return error, user was not found in db
    } else {
      user.changePassword(req.body.oldpassword, req.body.newpassword, function(err) {
         if(err) {
                  if(err.name === 'IncorrectPasswordError'){
                       res.json({ success: false, message: 'Incorrect password' }); // Return error
                  }else {
                      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong!! Please try again after sometimes.' });
                  }
        } else {
          res.json({ success: true, message: 'Your password has been changed successfully' });
         }
       })
    }
  }
});
});
```

If you want to change the password without using the old password you can use setPassword method. Here is an example

```
 user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err,user){
if (err) {
    res.json({success: false, message: 'Password could not be saved. Please try again!'})
} else { 
  res.json({success: true, message: 'Your new password has been saved successfully'})
         } 
         });
```